# How to deploy Sitecore website from local to Server

Tags: deployment, sitecore

I am new in Sitecore Website development. I just want to know how to deploy the sitecore website from my local to any server.
Which files are needed for deployment and how to deploy ?
I have read this article [ONECLICK DEPLOYMENT FOR SITECORE - PERFECTION IS A MOVING TARGET](http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/best-practice-blogs/jan-hebnes/posts/2012/09/oneclick-deployment-for-sitecore.aspx) but i did not understand how to deploy it.
Share your answer please..

Comment: Just copy the webroot and the databases and set the correct data path in the config. and use the correct license.xml file. or use one of the more advanced approach in the answere from sitecore_Climber

Comment: @JanBluemink nice blogpost you made regarding deployment.

Answer (score 6):

You have a lot of options for deployment a Sitecore Solution . Please check below blogs:

[Unicorn Auto deploy Sitecore items using Unicorn and TeamCity](http://andrew.lansdowne.me/2013/06/07/auto-deploy-sitecore-items-using-unicorn-and-teamcity/)

[TDS Continuous Integration & Deployment With Sitecore](http://www.jasonbert.com/2013/11/03/continuous-integration-deployment-with-sitecore/)

[TDS Automating Sitecore deployments with TFS and TDS](https://theagilecoder.wordpress.com/2013/01/26/automating-sitecore-deployments-with-tfs-and-tds/)

Setting Up a Sitecore Solution – Part 2 TDS and Build Configurations - See more at: http://jockstothecore.com/setting-up-a-sitecore-solution-part-2-tds-and-build-configurations/#sthash.OHxxJfMc.dpuf

Setting Up a Sitecore Solution – Part 2 TDS and Build Configurations - See more at: http://jockstothecore.com/setting-up-a-sitecore-solution-part-2-tds-and-build-configurations/#sthash.OHxxJfMc.dpuf

PowerShell http://blog.najmanowicz.com/2014/11/03/update-to-state-of-knowledge-for-powershell-extensions-for-sitecore-november-2014

Overview of Tools http://cardinalcore.co.uk/2015/07/15/why-tfs-is-the-probably-the-worst-choice-for-sitecore/

On this [link](http://sitecore.stockpick.nl/english/development-and-deployment/) you can see more details about Sitecore Deployment.

Comment: Whoever downvoted: any reason why? This answers cover N different approach of how this can be solved. +1

Comment: I also didn't understand why it was down voted. Question is not really good but it's good to know multiple way to deploy.

Comment: I didn't vote either way, the question is very very bad but the answer looks more like a [Link Only answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers). Possible reason.

Comment: Why the question has not gained enough votes yet to close, is the real mystery. Downvoting this answer will not matter after that.